# Problemas con funcion context api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy creando un login con context api, desde el componente consumo ciertas funciones que estan contenidas en el provider, si hago la prueba a nivel de componente no me aparece ningun error, no asi cuando cambio estas funciones y las llamo desde el componente a traves de context consumer, me da el siguiente error:

**TypeError: action.fetchData is not a function**

mi codigo del componente login es el siguiente:

```
  import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
  import { Context } from '../../store/TheContext';

export class Login extends React.Component {

render() {
    return(
        <Fragment>
            <Context.Consumer> 
                {action => {
                    return(
                        <form onSubmit={e => action.submitLogin(e)}>
                            <input type="text" onChange={e => action.fetchData(e)} name="username" placeholder="username"></input>
                            <input type="password" onChange={e => action.fetchData(e)} name="password" placeholder="password"></input>
                            <button type="submit">Log in</button>
                        </form>
                    )
                }}
            </Context.Consumer>
        </Fragment>
    )
}
}
```

en tanto el del provider en donde tengo contenidas las funciones para el login:

```
import React from 'react';

export const Context = React.createContext();

export class TheProvider extends React.Component {

// initial obj state, this obj has store and actions (methods)
state = {
    // login data:
    loginData: {}

}

aprieta(e) {
    alert('click');
}

/* LOGIN ACTIONS */
fetchData = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const data = { [name]: value };
    const newData = { ...this.state.loginData, ...data }
    this.setState({
        loginData: newData
    })
}

submitLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(e);
    let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/rest-auth/login/';

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state.loginData),
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then(resp => {
        console.log(resp.status);
        return resp.json();
    })
}

render(){
    return(
        <Context.Provider value={this.state}>
            {this.props.children}
        </Context.Provider>
    )
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que no estás pasando las funciones al contexto, deberías añadirlas a la hora de pasar el objeto, te muestro un ejemplo:

```
render(){
    const myContext = {
      ...this.state,
      submitLogin: this.submitLogin,
      fetchData: this.fetchData,
    };

    return(
        <Context.Provider value={myContext}>
            {this.props.children}
        </Context.Provider>
    )
}
```

Comment: gracias x la respuesta ayer intente ello y no me tomaron lo revisare de nuevo

Comment: no hay de que, espero que te haya servido.

Comment: gracias me sirvio :D, pero es raro igual anteriormente hice un context de la misma manera presentada arriba  solo que claro metia las funciones en el state y me salia :/